# Add up & sort a spreadsheet column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code. It's purpose is to add up and sort another columns Data. I tweaked it to fulfil my purpose, but I'm sure it can be cleaned up.

The only problem I have with its function is it leaves a trailing zero if the last item in the referenced list is text.

Can this be changed without altering how it currently reacts to text? Occasionally, I want the zero's if they fall within the middle of the referenced cells, but never if the last cell is text.

My VBA skills are very basic. I can generally alter a piece of code to do what I want, but have no idea on how to fix it.

```
Public Sub SumCages()
Dim current_row, summary_row, item_total As Integer

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 7) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 7)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 7))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 8) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 8) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 7) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 8) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 11) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 11)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 11))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 12) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 12) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 11) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 12) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 15) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 15)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 15))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 16) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 16) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 15) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 16) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 20) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 20) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 20) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 23) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 23)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 23))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 24) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 24) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 23) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 24) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 27) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 27)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 27))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 28) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 28) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 27) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 28) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 31) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 31)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 31))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 32) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 32) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 31) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 32) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 35) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 35)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 35))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 36) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 36) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 35) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 36) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 39) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 39)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 39))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 40) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 40) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 39) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 40) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 43) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 43)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 43))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 44) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 44) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 43) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 44) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 47) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 47)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 47))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 48) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 48) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 47) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 48) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 51) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 51)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 51))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 52) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 52) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 51) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 52) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 55) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 55)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 55))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 56) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 56) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 55) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 56) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 59) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 59)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 59))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 60) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 60) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 59) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 60) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 63) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 63)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 63))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 64) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 64) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 63) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 64) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 67) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 67)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 67))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 68) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 68) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 67) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 68) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 71) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 71)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 71))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 72) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 72) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 71) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 72) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 75) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 75)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 75))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 76) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 76) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 75) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 76) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 79) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 79)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 79))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 80) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 80) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 79) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 80) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 83) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 83)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 83))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 84) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 84) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 83) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 84) = item_total

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 87) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 87)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 87))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 88) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 88) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 87) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 88) = item_total

End Sub
```

Comment: At first glance this looks very repetitive; I'll take a deeper look a bit later, but for now I'm pretty sure you can write a function that starts with `current_row = 45` and ends with `Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, column) = item_total`, and call it as many times as you're repeating this code block. Copy+Paste is never a good sign when coding...

Comment: How and where is the sorting taking place?

Answer (score 4):

There are many iterative structures in VBA, but I think the one that would be most useful here is `For...Next...Step`; in your case, looks like `Step` should be 4, looping from 7 to 87.

All of your code blocks look very, very similar. I would only keep a single block and replace the hard-coded "magic numbers" with variables.

Something like this:

```
Private Const SUMMARY_ROW As Integer = 44
Private Const START_ROW As Integer = 45 'these two never change.
'...and if they ever do, that's the only place you need to change them.

Public Sub SumCages()
    Dim c As Integer
    For c = 7 To 87 Step 4 'start at 7 and +4 per iteration, up to 87
        CalculateTotal c
    Next
End Sub
```

The `CalculateTotal` procedure is nothing more than one of your code blocks, with the hard-coded row numbers replaced by the `SumColumn` parameter, which comes from the loop above.

Notice variables' names; variables are your friends, whenever you find yourself repeating a given operation (like, `Sheet8.Cells(current_row + 1, SumColumn)`), you can improve readability by adding a variable - this way at a glance you know two different places are talking about the same thing.

```
Private Sub CalculateTotal(sumColumn As Integer)

    Dim currentRow  As Integer
    Dim targetRow   As Integer
    Dim columnTotal As Integer
    Dim thisValue   As String

    currentRow = START_ROW
    targetRow = SUMMARY_ROW
    targetColumn = sumColumn + 1

    With Sheet8 ' this avoids having to specify it every time

        thisValue = .Cells(currentRow, sumColumn)

        While thisValue <> vbNullString

            If IsNumeric(thisValue) Then

                'this is where the sum actually takes place:
                columnTotal = columnTotal + Val(thisValue)

            Else
                If columnTotal > 0 Then

                    .Cells(targetRow + 1, targetColumn) = columnTotal

                Else

                    targetRow = targetRow + 1 'not sure I get why this is done...
                    currentRow = currentRow - 1 '...and this is even more confusing...
                    .Cells(targetRow, targetColumn) = thisValue

                End If

                'this is likely throwing off your total!
                columnTotal = 0
            End If

            currentRow = currentRow + 1
            thisValue = .Cells(currentRow, SumColumn)
        Wend

        .Cells(targetRow, targetColumn) = columnTotal

    End With
End Sub
```

It would be nice if you could post a screenshot of what the result looks like, because it's quite confusing (to me, at least) why you're incrementing your write-to row and then decrementing your loop counter, but only when you hit a non-numeric value.

To me it looks like what you have as `current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement` should really read `summary_row = summary_row - 1 ' Correct advancement`, because I would think it's an infinite loop written like this.